# Proving that given two linearly independent vectors in a plane, any third vector in that same plane is linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra

Given that $$U =  \{\alpha i + \beta k | α,β ∈\mathbb R\}$$
Write down two linearly independent vectors $u, v$ in this set.

Show that if you take any third vector $w ∈ U$ ,then the three vectors $u, v, w$ are linearly dependent.

My half attempt: $$\mathbf v = \{0\mathbf i + 1\mathbf k\} $$
$$\mathbf u = \{1\mathbf i + 0\mathbf k\} $$

I'm basically stuck here. Any help/clarification is greatly appreciated (:
Side note: how do you go about proving this without using matrices?

Comment: How are $i$ and $k$ defined?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like $U$ has dimension 2. Meaning that two linearly independent vectors form a basis. Hence, any third vector can be written as a linear combination of your two basis elements. Maybe you can work your way from here.